# Marshalling error while using OPENSAML2 in a servlet environment (Tomcat web server)

Tags: java, servlets, single-sign-on, saml, opensaml

I am trying to setup my Service provider using OpenSAML2 libraries. I am trying to set up a servlet which would accept HttpRequest from user's browser and based on the request parameters I want to create a SAML Authentication request packet.

I am able to create the SAML packet, however I want to Base64 encode the SAML so that I can redirect the user browser to the Identity provider server. In order to do that I am trying to marshall the SAML Authentication Request using 'org.opensaml.saml2.core.impl.AuthnRequestMarshaller#marshall(AuthnRequest)'.

This works fine when I try it outside of the web server environment (standalone JAVA application). However when I run it as a servlet component I get an error saying "No marshaller available for {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion}Issuer, child of {urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol}AuthnRequest", where Issuer is a component of the AuthnRequest object.

I am using Tomcat 5.5.34 webserver. It would be nice if someone can help me figure out whats happening here. It would help others trying to write their own Service Providers as well. Surprisingly very less documentation is available for this.

Thanks,
Kaustubh

Answer (score 2):

You need to have following jars inside Tomcat common/endorsed directory..

- resolver-2.9.1.jar
- serializer-2.9.1.jar
- xalan-2.7.1.jar
- xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar
- xml-apis-2.9.1.jar

[Here](http://wso2.org/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server) is an example of SAML2 service provider [also includes the sample WAR].

Answer (score 0):

Prabath's answer is on the dot. I faced the same issue, and resolved it by endorsing xalan and xerces in the Sun iJDK. Check out the official guide from the [Shibboleth site](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManual). Look under "Installing the Library" for openSAML deployment requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this by introducing this line of code - `DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();`.

```
private AuthnRequest buildSAMLRequest(String samlReqID) throws Exception {

    AuthnRequestBuilder authnRequestBuilder = new AuthnRequestBuilder();
    AuthnRequest authnRequest = authnRequestBuilder.buildObject();

    DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();
    authnRequest.setID(samlReqID);
    authnRequest.setIssuer(createSAMLIssuer());
    authnRequest.setDestination(DESTINATION);
    authnRequest.setSignature(createSAMLSignature());
    authnRequest.setAssertionConsumerServiceURL(ASSERTION_CONSUMER_SERVICE_URL);
    authnRequest.setProtocolBinding(PROTOCOL_BINDING);
    authnRequest.setIssueInstant(DateTime.now());

    return authnRequest;
}


private void parseRequest(AuthnRequest authnRequest) throws Exception {
    Element responseElement = marshall(authnRequest);
    String responseStr = convertElementToString(responseElement);
    System.out.println("SAML Response is: " + responseStr);
    String base64Response = generateBase64EncodedString(responseStr.getBytes());
    System.out.println("Base 64 Encoded Response: ");
    System.out.println(base64Response);
}

private String generateBase64EncodedString(byte[] bytes) {
    Base64.Encoder base64Enc = Base64.getEncoder();
    return base64Enc.encodeToString(bytes);
}

private String convertElementToString(Element element) {
    Writer outputWriter = new StringWriter();
    XMLHelper.writeNode(element, outputWriter);
    return outputWriter.toString();
}

private Element marshall(AuthnRequest response) throws Exception {
    AuthnRequestMarshaller marshaller = new AuthnRequestMarshaller();
    return marshaller.marshall(response);
}

private Issuer createSAMLIssuer() {
    IssuerBuilder issuerBuilder = new IssuerBuilder();
    Issuer issuer = issuerBuilder.buildObject();
    issuer.setValue(ISSUER);
    return issuer;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    GenSAMLRequest gen = new GenSAMLRequest();
    AuthnRequest authnRequest = gen.buildSAMLRequest(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    gen.parseRequest(authnRequest);
}
```